# Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialise the native Bugsnag Android client

Tags: java, reactjs, native, bugsnag

Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialise the native Bugsnag Android client, please check you have added Bugsnag.start() in the onCreate() method of your Application subclass

Comment: Hi - if you could send your full Bugsnag configuration code into support@bugsnag.com we'd be happy to investigate this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while upgrading my *React Native* version from 0.66 to 0.68.2.

Referring the docs from *Bugsnag community*:

1. Add the following import in your MainApplication.java class inside android folder of your project -

> import com.bugsnag.android.Bugsnag;

2. Add `Bugsnag.start(this);` inside your onCreate Method as below:

> ```
> public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
>
>         @Override
>
>         public void onCreate() {
>
>             super.onCreate();
>
>             Bugsnag.start(this);
>
>             // ...
>         }
>     }
> ```

I got this error resolved using the above code, let me know if this helps you too.